# Butt joint concrete table

Tags: concrete, table

I am building a 4' x 10' concrete table top. Because of the weight of the top, 2" thick would be around the 800 lbs range, I am breaking it into 2 parts. This will create a butt joint and just want to get some feedback about what I am thinking of doing.

When creating form, was thinking of not caulking the form to create a 90 degree edge. When butted together, would be less likely to show as opposed to two rounded edges coming together.  To even get a better joint, was thinking of butting them together and then use a diamond blade to make one cut that should join better, I think.

The next part is joining them together--dowelling the two pieces together, drilling holes in each piece, cut a piece of 3/8" rebar and epoxy to hold them together.  While drying, use calmps to keep the pieces even.  After that, I will be using a grinding disk to expose aggregate and then polish.

Finally, choice of concrete--leaning heavily towards Quickrete Counter top but keep seeing people post about using Rapid Set Mortar mix.

Would love to hear some comments on what I am trying to do.

Thanks.

Comment: Most mortar does not include aggregate(stone).  Imagine some fancy-dandy(nicer than what is in cement mix) stone can be added.  Rebar or similar probably will hold the two pieces together, but would not put my toes under it unless it had good support under it, holding it up.

Comment: If you permanently join the two together, the whole point of having two pieces you can more easily move is then lost.

Comment: Asking for comments is akin to asking for opinions and that, as noted in the [tour] and [help] is off-topic. Also, while this is all about your counter top, it's rather broad - you're really asking 3 questions: 1) how to make the form at the butt edge, 2) how to join them, 3) what concrete to use. Please [edit] to ask only one question at a time, then ask the other 2 separately. It's just how we roll 'round here.

Comment: Having a joint I believe it will always end up showing even if dowels are used. I use white Portland cement and add mix with clean sand and pea gravel , salt & pepper , Texas gold are 2 of the rock colors I use. for some cool edging add  glow stones along the edges and from experience I suggest if you create a pattern some putty or something to help hold the pieces in place while filling the form they will move if not. I agree with ecrnewal as a seam will not hide well and dowels may even cause cracks on the largest counter I did we poured in place and ran thick way more work but it was nice.